# Como cargar un checkbox que ya ha sido guardo y que al editar ya aparezca checkeado en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario que me guarda checkbox y quisiera que al momento de querer editar me aparezcan los checkbox que había seleccionado anteriormente 
Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código del formulario editar es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include "conexion/db.php";
    $id = $_GET['Id_situ'];
    $sam = "SELECT * FROM estado
    where  Id_situ = '$id'";
    $sal = $cone->query($sam);
    $row = $sal->fetch_assoc();
    ?>

    <form>
        <center>
            <h1>Pruebaaaa</h1><br><br>

            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="act" value="<?php if($row['Soltero'] == "Si"){ echo 'Checked: '.checked.''; }?>" >
            <label>Soltero</label for = "act">

                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="act2" value="<?php if($row['Casado'] == "Si"){ echo 'Checked: '.checked.''; }?>" >
                <label>Casado</label for = "act2">

                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="act3" value="<?php if($row['Uni'] == "Si"){ echo 'Checked: '.checked.''; }?>" >
                    <label>Union libre</label for = "act3">
        </center>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ya he visto el error.

Tú intentas hacer algo así:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="checked">
```

Cuando en realidad se hace así:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

Te paso el dataset y el código en PHP para que puedas hacer las comprobaciones necesarias:

```
CREATE TABLE estado(
  Id_situ int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Soltero varchar(2),
  Casado varchar(2),
  Uni varchar(2)
  );
INSERT INTO estado (Soltero, Casado, Uni) VALUES
  ('No','No','No'),
  ('No','','No'),
  ('No','No','No'),
  ('','No','No'),
  ('No','Si','No'),
  ('No','No','Si');
```

Código en PHP con algunas modificaciones para realizar la depuración:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $cone = new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
    //include "conexion/db.php";
    if(isset($_GET['Id_situ'])){
        $id = $_GET['Id_situ'];
        $sam = "SELECT * FROM estado
        where  Id_situ = '$id'";
        $sal = $cone->query($sam);
        $row = $sal->fetch_assoc();
    ?>

    <form>
        <center>
            <h1>Pruebaaaa</h1><br><br>

            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="act" <?php if($row['Soltero'] == "Si"){ echo 'Checked'; }?> >
            <label>Soltero</label for = "act">

            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="act2" <?php if($row['Casado'] == "Si"){ echo 'Checked'; }?> >
            <label>Casado</label for = "act2">

            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="act3" <?php if($row['Uni'] == "Si"){ echo 'Checked'; }?> >
            <label>Union libre</label for = "act3">

            <?php
            }
                $r=$cone->query("
                    SELECT * FROM estado;
                ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $txt='<table border>';
                foreach($r as $l){
                    $txt.='<tr>';
                    foreach($l as $campo=>$c){
                        $txt.='<td>'.$c.'</td>';
                        if($campo=='Uni')
                            $txt.='<td><a href="?Id_situ='.$l['Id_situ'].'">Agregar</a></td>';
                    }
                    $txt.='</tr>';
                }
                $txt.='<table>';
                echo $txt;

            ?>

        </center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```